# Group and Sum With Select Many C#?

Tags: c#, linq, concatenation, grouping

I have an incoming array with a count per row and a string which represents one or more key's split by underscore.

for each key I'd like to group and sum the total where if the key appears in a row with a total of 5, each item split by the underscore have their total increased by 5.

I was just wondering how this would be represented in linq...

```
 class Owl
    {
        public int SpeciesCount { get; set; }
        public string BandIdentifier { get; set; }
    }

public class GoOwl
{
    public GoOwl(Owl[] owls)
    {
       //just making a list of test data to illustrate what would be coming in on the array
        var owlList = new List<Owl>();
        owlList.Add(new Owl { SpeciesCount = 2, BandIdentifier = "OWL1" });
        owlList.Add(new Owl { SpeciesCount = 1, BandIdentifier = "OWL1_OWL2_OWL3" });
        owlList.Add(new Owl { SpeciesCount = 2, BandIdentifier = "OWL3" });
        owlList.Add(new Owl { SpeciesCount = 5, BandIdentifier = "OWL2_OWL3" });

        //i'd ideally like to have something like a row for each band identifier split on underscore plus a total species count..
        //where you'd sum the species count for each underscored item and group


    }
}
```

the following would be the desired output as single Owl objects

```
["OWL1", 3]
["OWL2", 6]
["OWL3", 8]
```

I'm still not quite getting SelectMany..

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fluent sytnax:

```
//For each 'owlItem' in the owlList, select an anonymous objects for each key in the BandIdentifier string, keeping track of the associated SpeciesCount
//Since each call to Split('_').Select(...) produces an IEnumerable of those anonymous objects, use SelectMany to flatten the IEnumerable to IEnumerables 
owlList.SelectMany(owlItem => owlItem.BandIdentifier.Split('_')
                .Select(key => new { OwlKey = key, owlItem.SpeciesCount }))
            //Group together those anonymous objects if they share the same key
            .GroupBy(info => info.OwlKey)
            //For each of the groups, sum together all the associated SpeciesCounts
            .Select(group => new { group.Key, SpeciesCount = group.Sum(info => info.SpeciesCount) })'
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! would you mind explaining how the selectmany works in that instance? i know it flattens out nested collections so in this instance is it doing the follwing where you'd have [OWL1 2] [OWL 1 1] [OWL2 1] [OWL3 1] [OWL3 2] [OWL2 5] [OWL3 5] then the group by groups on the key then you can sum?

Comment: Each call to .Split('_').Select(...) produces an IEnumerable.  Since we are calling that method chain for each element of the owlList variable, we have an IEnumerable of IEnumerables, which can be flattened using SelectMany.  In other words, since each element of your list produces a list of OwlKey/SpeciesCount combinations, we need to flatten out the generated list of lists before we start grouping and summing.

Comment: Thanks Ben and thank you for the explanation I do appreciate you taking the time! :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you want this:

```
var results =
    owlList.SelectMany(owl => owl.BandIdentifier.Split('_'), 
                       (owl, band) => new { owl, band })
           .GroupBy(x => x.band)
           .Select(group => new Owl 
                   {
                       BandIdentifier = group.Key
                       SpeciesCount = group.Sum(g => g.SpeciesCount)
                   });
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var results =
    from owl in owlList
    from band in owl.BandIdentifier.Split('_')
    group owl by band into group
    select new Owl {
        BandIdentifier = group.Key
        SpeciesCount = group.Sum(g => g.SpeciesCount)
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var owlResults = owlList
            //Use SelectMany to split and select all species
            //and have a select to get the count along with the species
            .SelectMany(O => O.BandIdentifier.Split('_')
                .Select(owl => new { Species = owl, Count = O.SpeciesCount }))
            //Here you can group and get the sum 
            .GroupBy(O => O.Species)
            .Select(owl => new { Species = owl.Key, Count = owl.Sum(o => o.Count) });
```